# A* Search Algorithm causes StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, search, artificial-intelligence

I am creating a 8 puzzle solver using A* Search.

I believe the error is in my Search.class found below. However I have also attached the other 2 classes just in case.

**Search Class**

```
public class Search {

/**
 * Active instance of <code>Board</code>
 */
private Board board;

/**
 * Set of fringes
 */
private ArrayList<Integer> fringes = new ArrayList<>();

/**
 * Current nodes
 */
private int node;

/**
 * Map linking tiles(by number) to the goal state
 */
private static Map<Integer, int[]> goalStates = new HashMap<>();

/**
 * g value
 */
private int g = 0;

/**
 * Is the search complete
 */
private boolean searchComplete = false;

/**
 * The last move
 */
private int lastMove = 0;

/**
 * Fills goalStates Map
 */
static {
    goalStates.put(1, new int[]{0, 0});
    goalStates.put(2, new int[]{1, 0});
    goalStates.put(3, new int[]{2, 0});
    goalStates.put(4, new int[]{0, 1});
    goalStates.put(5, new int[]{1, 1});
    goalStates.put(6, new int[]{2, 1});
    goalStates.put(7, new int[]{0, 2});
    goalStates.put(8, new int[]{1, 2});
};

/**
 * Construct the <code>Search</code> instance
 *
 * @param board
 *      The board
 */
public Search(Board board){
    this.board = board;

    searchAlgo();
}

/**
 * Main search algorithm
 */
private void searchAlgo() {

    ArrayList<Integer> nodeFValues = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Tile> nodeTiles = new ArrayList<>();

    /* Stores all the f values for the nodes in the fringe */
    for(Tile tile: board.checkNeighbouringTiles(board.findTile(0))){

        if(lastMove != tile.getNumber()) {
            nodeFValues.add(node(tile));
            nodeTiles.add(tile);
        }

    }

    /* Gets the minimum fringe */
    int minFValueIndex = nodeFValues.indexOf(Collections.min(nodeFValues));

    /* If there are no tiles out of place then you are at goal state */
    if (tilesOutOfPlaceHeuristic(board) == 0){
        System.out.println("Complete");
        board.print();
        searchComplete = true;

        return;
    }

    /* Goes to the node with the lowest f value. */
    board.moveTile(board.findTile(0),
            nodeTiles.get(minFValueIndex).getXPosition(),
            nodeTiles.get(minFValueIndex).getYPosition());

    lastMove = nodeTiles.get(minFValueIndex).getNumber();

    g += 1;

    /* If search is incomplete, it recursively calls itself */
    if(!searchComplete)
        searchAlgo();


}

/**
 * Represents each node
 *
 * @param tile
 *      The tile to be moved in the node
 * @return
 *      f value
 */
private int node(Tile tile){

    /** Initialises new board object */
    Board nodeBoard = new Board(board.getNumbers());

    nodeBoard.moveTile(nodeBoard.findTile(0), tile.getXPosition(), tile.getYPosition());

    int h1 = tilesOutOfPlaceHeuristic(nodeBoard);
    int h2 = manhattanHeuristic(nodeBoard);

    int f = g + h2;

    return f;
}

/**
 * Calculates horizontal and vertical distances of tiles from their proper places.
 * Admissible Heuristic.
 *
 * @return
 *      Sum of horizontal and vertical distances of tiles from their proper places.
 */
private int manhattanHeuristic(Board board) {

    int sum = 0;
    ArrayList<Tile> tiles = board.getTiles();
    int[] goalState;
    int goalX;
    int goalY;
    int differenceX;
    int differenceY;

    for(Tile tile: tiles){

        if(tile.getNumber() != 0) {
            goalState = goalStates.get(tile.getNumber());
            goalX = goalState[0];
            goalY = goalState[1];

            differenceX = goalX - tile.getXPosition();
            differenceY = goalY - tile.getYPosition();

            sum += Math.abs(differenceX) + Math.abs(differenceY);
        }

    }

    return sum;
}

/**
 * Calculates number of tiles out of place. Admissible Heuristic.
 *
 * @return
 *      Number of tiles out of place
 */
private int tilesOutOfPlaceHeuristic(Board board) {

    int tilesInWrongPlace = 0;
    ArrayList<Tile> tiles = board.getTiles();

    for(Tile tile: tiles){

        if(tile.getNumber() != 0) {
            if ((tile.getXPosition() != goalStates.get(tile.getNumber())[0])
                    || (tile.getYPosition() != goalStates.get(tile.getNumber())[1])){
                tilesInWrongPlace += 1;
            }
        }

    }

    return tilesInWrongPlace;
}


}
```

**Board Class:**

```
 public class Board {

/**
 * Numbers in the board
 */
private int[][] numbers = {};

private int rows = 3;
private int columns = 3;

/**
 * The board
 */
private ArrayList<Tile> board = new ArrayList();

/**
 * Constructs a <code>Board</code> instance and fills
 * it with <code>Tile</code> instances
 */
public Board(int[][] numbers) {

    this.numbers = numbers;
    int j = 0;

    for(int[] row: numbers){

        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            board.add(new Tile(row[i], i, j));
        }

        j += 1;
    }

}

/**
 * @return
 *      Numbers for board
 */
public int[][] getNumbers(){

    return numbers;
}

/**
 * @return
 *      Tiles in board
 */
public ArrayList<Tile> getTiles(){

    return board;
}

/**
 * Moves the specified <code>Tile</code> to the specified position.
 * Swaps positions with <code>Tile</code> at that position.
 *
 * @param tile
 *      <code>Tile</code> to be moved
 * @param x
 *      The horizontal position you want <code>Tile</code> to move to.
 * @param y
 *      The vertical position you want <code>Tile</code> to move to.
 */
public void moveTile(Tile tile, int x, int y) {

    int _x = tile.getXPosition();
    int _y = tile.getYPosition();

    Tile tileToBeMoved = tile;
    Tile tileAtPosition;

    if(findTile(x, y) != null) {
        tileAtPosition = findTile(x, y);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No tile exists at that position");
        return;
    }

    /* Move tileToBeMoved to chosen position */
    tileToBeMoved.setPosition(x, y);

    /* swap*/
    tileAtPosition.setPosition(_x, _y);


}

/**
 * Checks if neighbouring <code>Tile</code>s exist, if so, it returns the <code>Tile</code>
 *
 * @param tile
 *      Current <code>Tile</code>
 * @return
 *      Set of <code>Tile</code>s
 */
public ArrayList<Tile> checkNeighbouringTiles(Tile tile){

    ArrayList<Tile> neighbouringTiles = new ArrayList<>();

    int x = tile.getXPosition();
    int y = tile.getYPosition();

    /* Neighbour to the right of tile */
    int rightNeighbourX = x + 1;
    int rightNeighbourY = y;

    /* Neighbour to the left of tile */
    int leftNeighbourX = x - 1;
    int leftNeighbourY = y;

    /* Neighbour to the top of tile */
    int topNeighbourX = x;
    int topNeighbourY = y - 1;

    /* Neighbour to the bottom of tile */
    int bottomNeighbourX = x;
    int bottomNeighbourY = y + 1;


    for(Tile t: board) {
        if ((t.getXPosition() == rightNeighbourX) && (t.getYPosition() == rightNeighbourY)) {
            neighbouringTiles.add(t);

        } else if((t.getXPosition() == leftNeighbourX) && (t.getYPosition() == leftNeighbourY)){
            neighbouringTiles.add(t);

        } else if((t.getXPosition() == topNeighbourX) && (t.getYPosition() == topNeighbourY)){
            neighbouringTiles.add(t);

        } else if((t.getXPosition() == bottomNeighbourX) && (t.getYPosition() == bottomNeighbourY)){
            neighbouringTiles.add(t);
        }
    }

    return neighbouringTiles;
}

/**
 * Finds a <code>Tile</code> with matching position
 *
 * @param x
 *      The horizontal position
 * @param y
 *      The vertical position
 * @return
 *      matching <code>Tile</code>
 */
public Tile findTile(int x, int y){

    for(Tile t: board) {
        if(t.getXPosition() == x && t.getYPosition() == y)
            return t;
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Finds a <code>Tile</code> with matching number
 *
 * @param number
 *      The number on the <code>Tile</code>
 * @return
 *      matching <code>Tile</code>
 */
public Tile findTile(int number){

    for(Tile t: board) {
        if(t.getNumber() == number)
            return t;
    }

    return null;
}


/**
 *Prints the board
 */
public void print() {

    System.out.println("*=====*");

    for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
        System.out.print("||");

        for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
            if(findTile(i, j) != null){
                System.out.print(findTile(i, j).getNumber());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("||");
    }

    System.out.println("*=====*");

}

}
```

**Tile Class:**

```
public class Tile {

/**
 * Number on Tile
 */
private int number;

/**
 * Horizontal position of tile
 */
private int x;

/**
 * Vertical position of tile
 */
private int y;

/**
 * Constructs a <code>Tile</code> instance with a number and position.
 *
 * @param number
 *      The number for the <code>Tile</code>.
 * @param x
 *      The Horizontal position for the <code>Tile</code>.
 */
public Tile(int number, int x, int y){
    this.number = number;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

/**
 * @param x
 *      Horizontal position for the <code>Tile</code>
 * @param y
 *      Vertical position for the <code>Tile</code>
 */
public void setPosition(int x, int y){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

/**
 * @return
 *      Current horizontal position of <code>Tile</code>
 */
public int getXPosition(){

    return x;
}

/**
 * @return
 *      Current vertical position of <code>Tile</code>
 */
public int getYPosition(){

    return y;
}

/**
 * @param number
 *      Number on Tile
 */
public void setNumber(int number){

    this.number = number;
}

/**
 * @return
 *      Current number on tile
 */
public int getNumber(){

    return number;
}

}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){

    int[][] numbers = {
            {1, 0, 4},
            {3, 2, 6},
            {7, 5, 8}
    };

    Board board = new Board(numbers);


    Search search = new Search(board);

}
}
```

The following is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3175)
at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:246)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:220)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:212)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:443)
at Board.checkNeighbouringTiles(Board.java:138)
at Search.searchAlgo(Search.java:89)
```

Please note, in some cases there is no error but the complete answer(goal state) is provided.

Comment: Do you have a Stack Trace for the Exception that was raised?

Comment: The only reason for a stack overflow is an infinite recursion in searchAlgos which recalls itself at the end of the method if the search isn't completed. You can check this easy in your debugger.

Comment: @MatthewSpencer I have added the stack trace

Answer (score 1):

In your moveTile method, the tileToBeMoved is just a copy of a the Tile from the board.  It needs to get updated in the board ArrayList.  You should probably do something like:

```
board.get(indexOf(tileToBeMoved)).setPosition(x, y);
board.get(indexOf(tileAtPosition)).setPosition(_x, _y);
```

Otherwise when you call your searchAlgo method over and over, all the tiles will be in the same position every time.

Also, look at how your board is initialized and how you calculate your f values. You need to account for when neighbors are already in their correct location:

#### First pass:

Neighbors of 0: 1, 4, 2

F Values of Neighbors: {1, 0}, {4, 4}, {2, 1}

moveTile(0, 0, 0);

New Board:

{0, 1, 4},

{3, 2, 6},

{7, 5, 8}

#### Second pass:

Neighbors of 0: 1, 3

F Values of Neighbors: {1, 2}, {3, 5}

moveTile(0, 0, 1);

New Board:

{1, 0, 4},

{3, 2, 6},

{7, 5, 8}

See what's happening?

Comment: After more thoroughly examining your code I have expanded my answer.